# Как правильно создать задание CRON с последующей обработкой

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно создать задачу CRON в *Ubuntu server 17*?

Необходимо вызывать выполнение PHP скрипта каждую минуту?

Что я сделал:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -s http://myhost/script/tasck.php
```

Нужна помощь в реализации с обработкой, т.е. вызываем скрипт и получаем результат, потом обрабатываем на стороне *Ubuntu* или полученный результат вызываем с GET другого URL

Пользуюсь *WEBMIN Ubuntu*

При вызове скрипта я получаю тело ответа в формате JSON. Как полученный ответ обработать другим скриптом

Пример

```
/usr/bin/curl -s http://myhost/script/tasck.php => http://myhost/script/test.php
```

Это правильно?

Comment: ну так напишите на php/bash/perl/python/любой другой любимый язык скрипт, который сделает все, что нужно и добавьте его уже в крон.

Comment: непонятно, о чём вы спрашиваете. задание привели. оно не работает? для начала замените `*/1` на `*`, а то тавтология какая-то: «выполнять каждую минуту раз в минуту».

Comment: Да я уже поправил, всё работает. Но как можно перенаправить полученный результат?

Comment: Суть в том что скрипт написан на PHP и он лежит на хостинге, Ubuntu использую только в качестве MySQL и планировщика заданий. (я не силен в Linux)

Comment: Вопрос нисколько не связан с тем, как создавать задание крон -- вы уже умеете создавать новые строчки в кронтабе. А вопрос по взаимодействию скриптов, даже так -- по архитектуре, ибо можно несколькими способами расположить эти скрипты. Как минимум нужно переформулировать заголовок, как максимум -- закрыть таск. Когда выберите архитектуру -- тогда и спрашивайте "как сделать".

Comment: Какой результат вы получите от скрипта -- зависит от вас. Может вы захотите Plain text, может JSON... Задача слишком неконкретно описана, возможны очень разные варианты решения => закрыть вопрос как слишком общий.